How can I put the same character at point and mark?
Suppose that I have written bar, but decide that I wanted &bar&. I put point at b and mark at r. What now?
Some mode lets you do this by just typing a special character, such as [ in Markdown Mode, but this doesn't work for everything. I don't know a term for what I'm trying to do, so my searches for more info met a dead end.

Are you looking for electric-pair-mode perhaps?

@NickD That's handy and is what I often use, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get what I've specifically asked for,

Well, I don't understand what you've asked for. At the most basic level, you type & at point, do C-x C-x to exchange the mark and point and you type & again. Or you make a keyboard macro that will do that. Or you write a function that will do that. Is that enough? For different characters, you will need to specify the character that you want to add at the two places: how exactly do you want to do that? Ask for input? Or do it through some configuration?  You need to specify the parameters of what you are willing to accept.

Try selecting a region and evaluate, using M-:, the expression (insert-pair nil "&" "&")  If that works, then wrap it in an interactive function that prompts for user input to specify the OPEN and CLOSE arguments, which can be the same character used for both arguments.

Please don't leave questions orphaned: either follow up, or provide an answer if you have one.
